# Change the label of the reference in the references section

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex to manage my bibliography. I want to be able to change the label of citation and reference from [1] to **[Ref.1]** and eventually some color. I was able to change the label in the document by using :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib} 
@article{nature, 
       author      =   {Rosa Rademakers and Manuela Neumann and Ian R. Mackenzie}, 
       title      =   {Advances in understanding the molecular basis of frontotemporal dementia - elongated title}, 
       journal      =   {Nature Reviews Neurology}, 
       volume      =   {8}, 
       year      =   {2012}, 
       pages      =   {423-434}, 
       doi         =   {10.1038/nrneurol.2012.117},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, defernumbers=true, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{bracketcol}{RGB}{12,127,172}

\newcommand{\mkbibbracketscol}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{bracketcol}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketscol]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\cite{nature}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

but it only changes in the document and does not affect the bibliography section. I am asking how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can copy-paste and test your code, and suggest corrections. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase thank you for your comment! I added the MWE now do you think it is clear now?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it makes the question much more manageable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the citation labels in a `numeric` bibliography is controlled by the field format `labelnumberwidth`. You just have to give it the appropriate definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, defernumbers=true, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{bracketcol}{RGB}{12,127,172}

\newcommand{\mkbibbracketscol}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{bracketcol}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbracketscol{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketscol]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue label number both in citation and bibliography.]